# Why mysql performing scan operation, if index exists on channel column

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

i am having 3 tables,

```
testdata1: id (pri)                      -> 1000000 rows
testdata2: id (pri), channel (indexed),  -> 10000 rows
testdata3: id (pri)                      -> 1000 rows
```

on performing following query, i get scan on testdata2.

```
explain format=tree 
select * 
from testdata1 
inner join testdata2 on testdata1.id = testdata2.channel 
inner join testdata3 on testdata2.channel = testdata3.id 
where testdata1.id < 100;
```

```
EXPLAIN: -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=8014.20 rows=9984)
    -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=4519.80 rows=9984)
        -> Table scan on testdata2  (cost=1025.40 rows=9984)
        -> Filter: ((testdata1.id < 100) and (testdata1.id = testdata2.`channel`))  (cost=0.25 rows=1)
            -> Single-row index lookup on testdata1 using PRIMARY (id=testdata2.`channel`)  (cost=0.25 rows=1)
    -> Filter: (testdata2.`channel` = testdata3.id)  (cost=0.25 rows=1)
        -> Single-row index lookup on testdata3 using PRIMARY (id=testdata2.`channel`)  (cost=0.25 rows=1)
```

why is mysql not utilising index of **testdata2(channel)** column?

***UPDATE**

After running `analyze table testdata2`, mysql used the index.
**Is it necessary to use analyze table command after creating index?**

```
EXPLAIN: -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=241.34 rows=156)
    -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=186.85 rows=156)
        -> Filter: (testdata1.id < 100)  (cost=20.09 rows=99)
            -> Index range scan on testdata1 using PRIMARY over (id < 100)  (cost=20.09 rows=99)
        -> Index lookup on testdata2 using a_temp_index (channel=testdata1.id), with index condition: (testdata1.id = testdata2.`channel`)  (cost=1.53 rows=2)
    -> Filter: (testdata2.`channel` = testdata3.id)  (cost=0.25 rows=1)
        -> Single-row index lookup on testdata3 using PRIMARY (id=testdata2.`channel`)  (cost=0.25 rows=1)
```

Comment: Are you sure you have an index on `channel`? I'm testing your query in my local instance but I can't reproduce a table-scan unless I drop the index on `channel`. Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE <name>`  for each table, and edit your question to include that output.

Comment: *why is mysql not utilising index of testdata2(channel) column?* Server doesn't see the reason for to use this index. And I agree with it. PS. Do you really need in `SELECT *`? maybe a short list of columns which are needed really is more suitable? If none column from table `testdata2` needed then the index should be used.. Moreover, I'd exclude this table from FROM and use EXISTS in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html says:

> When the `innodb_stats_persistent` setting is enabled, run the `ANALYZE TABLE` statement for an InnoDB table after creating an index on that table.

This setting is on by default, so yes, it's recommended to run `ANALYZE TABLE` after creating an index.